# OpenCV cascade returning different detections for the same image

Tags: c++, opencv, detection, cascade

Lately, I have been training an OpenCV cascade for face detection and I realized that the same cascade is returning different detections for the same image.

You can find the image I've been using to test my cascade [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HgF2.jpg).

That's my code to test the detector:

```
Mat image1 = imread("path/to/image/021aa138-def8-44d4-8485-7a4735e11acb.jpg", CV_8UC3);
Mat image2 = imread("path/to/image/021aa138-def8-44d4-8485-7a4735e11acb.jpg", CV_8UC3);
CascadeClassifier cascade;
cascade.load("path/to/cascade/cascade_15.xml");

std::vector<Rect> rects1, rects2;
cascade.detectMultiScale(image1, rects1, 1.1, 3, 0, Size(20, 20), Size(150, 150));
cascade.detectMultiScale(image2, rects2, 1.1, 3, 0, Size(20, 20), Size(150, 150));

for (auto rect = rects1.begin(); rect != rects1.end(); rect++)
{
    cv::rectangle(image1, *rect, Scalar(0, 255, 0));
}

for (auto rect = rects2.begin(); rect != rects2.end(); rect++)
{
    cv::rectangle(image2, *rect, Scalar(0, 255, 0));
}

imshow("Image 1", image1);
waitKey(0);
imshow("Image 2", image2);
waitKey(0);
```

The parameters I used to train my cascade:

> opencv_traincascade.exe -data data -vec training_20x20_full_44010.vec -bg gt_neg.data -w 20 -h 20 -maxWeakCount 1000 -minHitRate 0.999 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.5 -mode ALL -numPos 5000 -numNeg 10000 -numStages 15

And the detection output can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsvot.png).

As you all see, I'm loading the same image and applying the same cascade with the same parameters, but I'm getting a different output every time I run my code. Another weird thing is that when I apply some of the original OpenCV cascades (*haarcascades_frontalface_*.xml*) I always get the same detections.

Anyone else has also faced this problem before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if you change to: Mat image1 = imread("path/to/image/1aa138-def8-44d4-8485-7a4735e11acb.jpg");
Mat image2 = imread("path/to/image/1aa138-def8-44d4-8485-7a4735e11acb.jpg");

Comment: can you try to remove the CV_8UC3 keyword from the imread call? There are different  special parameter keywords for imread. And cascade detection uses grayscale images as input afaik.

Comment: I've just tried doing what you said and I got the same result, unfortunately. Thank you for your help, tough.

Comment: are you using debug libraries in debug build and release libraries in release build? Afaik, haar cascade detection i deterministic. Did you try changing `imread(..., CV_8UC3)` to `imread(..., CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)`?

Comment: Do a cv::absdiff() for both images, and verify if they are exactly the same. (result should be na absolutely black image)